# Simple if-comparison in Python fails with float

Tags: python

Sorry für this incredible stupid beginners question but I fail with a simple comparison of two numeric values in python. That's my relevant code:

```
lastResult=1.0
currResult=repr(model.evaluate(xTest, yTest)[1]) # now currResult contains 0.0

if (currResult>lastResult):
  print("\nBetter result " +str(currResult) + " > " + str(lastResult))
```

Here the comparison fails, although currResult is smaller than lastResult, the if-condition is executed and I get some output

```
Better result 0.0 > 1.0
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You posted the wrong code .. If I replace the `currResult=repr(model.evaluate(xTest, yTest)[1])` with `0.0` nothing is printed. Maybe you have a scoping problem ?

Comment: you might want to switch to `print("\nBetter result {} > {}".format(currResult,lastResult))` or even `print(f"\nBetter result {currResult} > {lastResult}")` when you are at it -it is somewhat more modern

Comment: `currResult` check this variable type and value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple little error. `repr` returns a string. Use `int` instead. :D

@BlackBear Looks like it should return a float.

```
lastResult = 1.0
currResult = float(model.evaluate(xTest, yTest)[1])

# note that this is 0.0 > 1.0 and shouldn't run
if currResult > lastResult:
    print(f'\nBetter result {currResult} > {lastResult}')
```

Comment: I'd say `float` is more appropriate in this case

Comment: Sorry about that. I've edited my answer with appropriate changes :)